# How to use the two values in the url sent from one page in other in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, session, gridview

I have a homepage with a friend list and other page 'chatbox'. i have one dynamic list getting generated using Gridview. That list is the list of friends and when user clicks on the name of the friends, an Id of that friend's name and the id of the user( that is in session) must be passed to another page('chatbox.aspx').

Code:

HomePage1.aspx(partial code)

```
<asp:GridView GridLines="None" ID="GridView1" class="active bounceInDown" onClientClick="#chat-message"
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White"></AlternatingRowStyle>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Friends">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href='<%# "chatbox.aspx?User=" + Eval("Ownerid") + "?Friend=" + Eval("Friendid") %>'>
                        <%# Eval("FName") %>
                    </a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
```

On clicking to the name i can get the two values: userid and friend id in the url of the next page('chatbox.aspx') , i just want to know how do i use them for further coding in new page('chatbox.apsx').

Comment: So if i understand right, your just trying to access the querystring values in the next page correct? Are you accessing from the code behind?

Comment: Yes from chatbox.apsx.cs @Rickjames

Comment: @VDWWD beat me to it

Comment: Nope..still couldnt fetch it.

Comment: Post the code where you are attempting to access the querystring please.

Comment: Any luck getting this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
        int oid = new int();
        int pid = new int();
        if (Request.QueryString["User"] != null && Request.QueryString["Friend"] != null)
        {

                oid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["User"]);

                OwnerName.Visible = true;
                UserTable q = Class1.selectByID(oid);
                OwnerName.Text = q.LName;

            pid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Friend"]);
            FriendName.Visible = true;
            UserTable a = Class1.selectByID(pid);
            FriendName.Text = a.LName;


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would normally do something like this on the page that receives the url with the querystring.

```
//declare a variable to on the new page for the passed id
int Ownerid = new int();

//check if the querystring exists
if (Request.QueryString["User"] != null)
{
    //wrap the conversion in a try-catch blok because in a querystring a user can change the value
    try
    {
        //convert the querystring to a usable value
        Ownerid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["User"]);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Should it be "User" instead of "Ownerid"?

Comment: Because this how my URL looks like :http://localhost:54726/chatbox?User=1?Friend=7

Comment: yea i dont think that is valid, it should be :localhost:54726/chatbox?User=1&Friend=7

Comment: You'd really declare an int variable like that ??

Comment: @DhrumilPanchal, @Rick james , you're right, it should be `User`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Additional parameters in a query string should be seperated by & so

```
<a href='<%# "chatbox.aspx?User=" + Eval("Ownerid") + "&Friend=" + Eval("Friendid") %>'>
```

In your cs page you should be requesting User and Friend

```
var user = Request.QueryString["User"];
var friend = Request.QueryString["Friend"];
```